# Codeigniter Pagination Customization Sorting

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I need to customize codeigniter pagination. Currently my pagination is working like this. (I am using codeigniter pagination library)

[image]

I want my pagination to look and work like this

[image]

My Controller:

> public function index()
>       {

```
    //$data["title"]    =  "Home";
    $data["page_title"] =  "Home";
    $data["page_title_icon"] =  "<i class='fa fa-home' style='color:#31B0D5'></i>";

    $data['all_menu_label']         =  $this->home_model->get_all_menu_label();
    $data['all_scripts']            =  $this->home_model->get_all_scripts();


    $data["top_scripts"]            = $this->home_model->get_all_top_scripts();
    $data["recent_post_scripts"]    = $this->home_model->get_all_recent_post_scripts();


    //pagination settings
    $config['base_url'] = base_url('home/index');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('ci_scripts');
    $config['per_page'] = "8";
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
    $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);

    //config for bootstrap pagination class integration
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] = false;
    $config['last_link'] = false;
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo&nbsp;Previous Page';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next Page&nbsp;&raquo';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['page'] = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

    //call the model function to get the all scripts data          
    $data["home_body_script"]       = $this->home_model->get_all_scripts_for_home_body($config["per_page"], $data['page']);

    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data['view']       =   'home';
    $this->load->view('index',$data);
}
```

Can somebody/anybody help me?

Comment: Where is your code? See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pagination-in-codeigniter-the-complete-guide--cms-29030

Comment: i added my code.

Comment: You mostly need to set `$config['num_links'] = 3;` or however many page links you want on either side of your current page.

Comment: I don't know if you can get CI's pagination to produce the links you're after. [But there's this pagination plug-in that does.](https://github.com/jasongrimes/php-paginator)